# Does ML.NET not support Guid type DataFrameColumns?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ml.net

I'm attempting a price prediction model using ML.NET and am loading data from a database which can will have dynamic column names. To handle this I am building a `DataFrame` of the data and using it as the `IDataView` for the pipeline. The dataframe contains quite a few columns that are `PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<Guid>` types. These are categorical columns that get transformed with OneHotEncoding.

Example:

```
dataFrame.Columns.Add(new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<Guid>("CategoryId"));
```

When I try to train a model with the data using a FastTree Regression method, I get an exception with not much information:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Type is Guid'

Are Guid column types not supported? It would seem so, but I can't find any documentation on this at all.